# Time out and Windows console error in watir

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I'm trying to perform automated testing using Watir gem. I need to test whether I can upload an image file from my desktop.
The angular-js content

```
<input aria-invalid="false" tabindex="0" class="ng-pristine ng-valid 
ng-touched"   
ng-model="user.photo" 
onchange="angular.element(this).scope().file_selected(event)" type="file">
```

The ruby script

```
require 'watir'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'watir-webdriver/wait'
browser =  Watir::Browser.new :firefox
browser.goto 'https://54.69.254.137/webui#/landing'
browser.driver.manage.window.maximize
browser.button(:class =>'sign-in md-button md-default-theme').click
browser.text_field(:id =>'input_001').set('abcadmin@example.com')
browser.text_field(:id =>'input_002').set('password')
browser.button(:class =>'md-primary md-raised md-button md-default-theme').click
browser.button(:class =>'md-icon-button md-primary main-menu-toggle 
md-button md-default-theme').when_present.click
browser.link(:text =>'Edit Profile').when_present.click
imagefile = "C://Users//Admin-pc//Desktop//images.jpg"
browser.input(:class =>'ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched').when_present(60).click
myAutoIT = WIN32OLE.new("AutoitX3.Control")
myAutoIT.WinWaitActive("File Upload","",15) 
myAutoIT.Send("{ALT}n") 
myAutoIT.Send(imagefile) 
myAutoIT.ControlClick("File Upload","","&Open")
browser.element(aria_label:'Remove').click
```

I get the following error

```
irb(main):019:0> imagefile = "C://Users//Admin-pc//Desktop//images.jpg
=> "C://Users//Admin-pc//Desktop//images.jpg"
<put(:class =>'ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched').when_present(60).click
Watir::Wait::TimeoutError: timed out after 60 seconds, waiting for {:class =>   
"ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched", :tag_name=>"input"} to become present
from C:/Bitnami/rubystack-1.9.3-28/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-  
webdriver-0.8.0/lib/watir-webdriver/wait.rb:41:in `until'
from C:/Bitnami/rubystack-1.9.3-28/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-
webdriver-0.8.0/lib/watir-webdriver/wait.rb:119:in `method_missing'
from (irb):20
from C:/Bitnami/rubystack-1.9.3-28/ruby/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):021:0> myAutoIT = WIN32OLE.new("AutoitX3.Control")
NameError: uninitialized constant WIN32OLE
from (irb):21
from C:/Bitnami/rubystack-1.9.3-28/ruby/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):022:0> myAutoIT.WinWaitActive("File Upload","",15)
NoMethodError: undefined method `WinWaitActive' for nil:NilClass
from (irb):22
from C:/Bitnami/rubystack-1.9.3-28/ruby/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):023:0> myAutoIT.Send("{ALT}n")
NoMethodError: undefined method `Send' for nil:NilClass
from (irb):23
from C:/Bitnami/rubystack-1.9.3-28/ruby/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):024:0> myAutoIT.Send(imagefile)
NoMethodError: undefined method `Send' for nil:NilClass
from (irb):24
from C:/Bitnami/rubystack-1.9.3-28/ruby/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):025:0> myAutoIT.ControlClick("File Upload","","&Open")
NoMethodError: undefined method `ControlClick' for nil:NilClass
from (irb):25
from C:/Bitnami/rubystack-1.9.3-28/ruby/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):026:0> exit
```

It gives a time out error.However if I type manually on the console

```
browser.input(:class =>'ng-pristine ng-validng-touched').when_present(60).click
```

the input type works.I would really appreciate if someone helps to me understand what those errors are help me rectify it.

Comment: What do you mean that it works when you manually try it in the console? It looks like it is failing in your IRB console. Without seeing the page it is hard to help debug why the element is not being seen. However, you can look at [my blog for a list of common reasons](https://jkotests.wordpress.com/unable-to-locate-element/). Also note that there is a FileField class that handles the file inputs (ie you can probably avoid using AutoIT).

Comment: On typing browser.file_field(:class =>'ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched').when_present.set('C:\\Users\\Admin-pc\\Desktop\\images.jpg')

Comment: Is the file field actually visible to users? Do they interact with the native file field directly or is it hidden and populated when using some AngularJS control?

Comment: There is a visible input button named browse for the users to select a file from local directory.When I type the file_field command on irb console and run, it works and the field gets populated.However when I run the command as a ruby script it throws timeout error.